# Wireless 802.11/ac not working Netgear Nighthawk D700

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, 802.11ac

I have a [Netgear Nighthawk D7000](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/dsl-modems-routers/D7000.aspx) that's about 30ft away and behind two walls. In my desktop, I have a [TP-LINK Archer T9E AC1900](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TQEX7AQ).

I am connected to the D7000's 5G network via CenturyLink's GPON fiber with 1Gbps down and 1Gbps up bandwidth. I'm on Windows 8.1 and when I go to "view connection settings" it shows the protocol as 802.11n instead of 802.11ac.

Is this because Windows isn't aware of 802.11ac? Or is it because I'm missing a setting in my router/wireless card?

Answer (score 1):

Plambre,

Are you able to see the 5G network from any other devices? iPhone 6 has an 802.11ac wireless networking capabilities, so if you've got one of those that's an easy way to test whether or not your 5G network is enabled. Whatever your 2.4GHz network name is, usually there's a network with the same SSID with "-5G" appended to the end of it. Also, I believe you'll have to manually enable the 5G network from within the D7000's web console if you haven't done so already.

I have the same router and absolutely love it - let me know if you continue to have issues here.

Zach

Comment: Hi, yes I am connected to the -5G network. Here is what my router 5G settings look like: http://i.imgur.com/iHhZNBz.png

Answer (score 1):

I installed the TP-link wireless configuration utility and used that to connect to the Netgear and it connected via wireless AC. Kind of annoying that you can't connect with the card via AC via windows wireless utility.

Note that the TP-Link wireless configuration utility has to be installed in compatibility mode if you're on windows 8.1